# How to add extra color at top level on Achart Engine Bar Graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I am very much new to this issue, Never worked before on Achart Engine, I am trying to draw a bar graph using achart Engine.

Here is my code snap

```
productive =new int[] { 2000, 2500, 2700, 3000 };
neutral = new int[]{ 2200, 2700, 2900,2222 };
destructing = new int[]{ 2200, 2700, 2900,2222 };

   XYSeries ProductiveSeries = new XYSeries("Productive");
// Creating an XYSeries for Income
XYSeries NuetralSeries = new XYSeries("Nuetral");
XYSeries DescatringSeries = new XYSeries("Nuetral");
// Adding data to Income and Expense Series
for (int i = 0; i < CategoryNum; i++) {
    ProductiveSeries.add(i, productive[i]);
    NuetralSeries.add(i, neutral[i]);
    DescatringSeries.add(i, destructing[i]);
}

// Creating a dataset to hold each series
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
// Adding Income Series to the dataset
dataset.addSeries(ProductiveSeries);
dataset.addSeries(NuetralSeries);
// Adding Expense Series to dataset
dataset.addSeries(DescatringSeries);

// Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

// Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(220, 80, 80));
expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR);

// Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
expenseRenderer1.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 166, 0));
expenseRenderer1.setFillPoints(true);
expenseRenderer1.setLineWidth(2);
expenseRenderer1.setDisplayChartValues(true);
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
// Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income vs Expense Chart");
multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
for (int i = 0; i < CategoryNum; i++) {
    multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
}


multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);
multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer1);

// Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and
// multipleRenderer
Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(),
        dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

// Start Activity
startActivity(intent);
```

By using above code i am getting graph as shown on below image

[image]

Now what i want is ,as you can see one black circle is there,just below the value of 250, on that perticular part only ,i want to change color of that perticular column only, Can any one tell me how to do it?

Thanks